# IE, Chrome both open .TXT, .LOG files rather than passing to default program

Tags: browser, registry, file-association, vdi

Situation is this:  I have two Windows 7 systems available to me through the magic of virtual machines (VDI and VPOD). When I log in to either system, my profile information is sent to the machine, before I gain control.  In this manner, my settings move from machine to machine.  All good.

In both machines, I have set Notepad++ to be the default application for .txt/.log/.sql (and a host of other) files.

On the VDI, when I click on a web browser url that points to a file of the above type, it will open in Notepad++ (after prompting to be sure I want the file opened).  This is good behavior.

But on the VPOD, the files listed above will open in IE, as a plain-text web page.  I do not have the option to open in another program, directly.  Instead, I have to Save As... and then I can Open the file once it's saved.  And by this method, I can open the file in the editor.

My limited ability to test implies that this situation applies with IE8, IE11, Chrome, so it doesn't look (to me) like a browser problem, necessarily.  But again, that testing is necessarily limited.  It absolutely applies to IE8.

The support staff responsible for these systems are baffled and confused by all of this, and have seemingly run out of options (read, "they have given up").

Do any of you gurus know what might be the cause?  It is almost certainly machine-specific, since it always works on VDI, and never works on VPOD.  So I suspect it is in the registry, under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.  In fact, it might be something under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\CLASSES, but that's an educated guess.  Unfortunately, access to the registry - even in view mode - is out of the question for me.

I've been beating my head against the wall for ages because of this, and the (stone) wall is starting to show wear.  Sure would appreciate some guidance on this.

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: I'd be fascinated to know your workflow why it is necessary for you to edit web based .txt files?

Comment: Are you really asking me to justify my reason for wanting to know why Windows behavior is inconsistent between machines? Can we focus on the question, please, @toby? But if you must know, the editor I use has column indicators, line counts, regex searches, ability to cut out columns, and a host of other features not available in browsers. My job includes producing interface files that happen to be plain text, but extended features help in debugging.

Comment: I forgot to mention the interface files generated are only available by URL link